# How to cast void pointer returned by box2d?

Tags: c++, box2d

I have a wrapper class that holds a b2Body.

```
class Wrapper{

public:
     b2Body *body

     Wrapper(b2World &world){
         //Create the b2Body
        body->SetUserData(this);
     }

}
```

Now b2Body has a function `GetUserData()`, that returns `void*`

Since I know for a fact that the void* has to be of type wrapper, I try to cast it.

```
b2Body* bodies = world->GetBodyList();
    while (bodies) {

        if (bodies->GetUserData()!=NULL) {

            Wrapper *wrapper = (Wrapper*)bodies->GetUserData();;
```

But no matter how I cast it, the object has incorrect values for the actual members of the instance.

What is the correct way to cast void * to my class type so I can get the correct values ?

EDIT: I am trying to do what is described in this tutorial, but it doesn't work.

http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/user-data

The member variables of my "Wrapper" class, the equivalent of "Ball" in the tutorial, have incorrect values. I tried the static cast as well.

EDIT: The following works:

```
 //setting and retrieving an integer
  int myInt = 123;
  body->SetUserData( (void*)myInt );
  ...later...
  int udInt = (int)body->GetUserData();
```

But the following doesn't:

```
    this->body->SetUserData((void*)this);
    ..later....
    Wrapper *wrapper = (Wrapper*)(bodies->GetUserData());
```

Again all the member variables of wrapper are either incorrect or NULL. Even though Wrapper should contain the pointer b2Body that we call GetUserData() on, the b2Body that we access through wrapper->body has most of its members set to NULL too. Why is this happening ?

Comment: `this->body->SetUserData((void*)this);` is there _any_ posibility that `this` object was deleted before call to `GetUserData`?

Comment: You are right! That was the problem!

Answer (score 1):

You want to *try* `reinterpret_cast<Wrapper*>`:

```
Wrapper* wrapper = reinterpret_cast<Wrapper*>(bodies->GetUserData());
```

Comment: I just tried that. Same result. Nothing crashes, but the values of the public members of Wrapper are incorrect

Comment: then you're not getting a `Wrapper`, are you, or you have allignment problems, or ABI issues, or....

Comment: Well it can't be anything else. I don't control Box2d (that's a third party library), and the cast works in Objective-c. I'm new to C++, and don't know how to get the same cast to work.

Comment: but this is all frought with dangers anyway, maybe you want to communicate the data to C++ through Objective-C or some other better design

Comment: This should be straightforward. I'm new to C++ so I must be doing something dumb. Functions called under bodies give the expected result (e.g.: bodies->GetPosition() returns the expected value), but whatever is a member function of the wrapper class has an incorrect value. So wrapper->objectId has some huge number like 12312233. So problem with casting or setting the user data

Comment: If you have such problems I would like you to show code when you actually create and put `Wrapper` objects' pointers into this B2D bodies list.

Comment: That happens when you call SetUserData(). See my code above. Box2d is an external framework, so it does everything.